# pre-populate shared preference file

Tags: java, android, default, shared, preference

I'm just starting to write a new android app and wanted to have a clean design.

I want some variables to be initiated with a default value. Those default values should all be in one file called settings (or something similar). However the user should be able to change some of those values and save them.

Changing user settings is normally done in shared preferences files. However I did not found out how I can pre-populate them with my default values.

Is there any other way how I can have some sort of a settings file that already has values in it? I don't want to hardcode values in my java application as I want to have a single file to adjust when I need to change the default values.

Secondary goal: I would like if the user would not lose his saved values when the app updates.

Can anyone give me some hints where to search?